# How to rotate a video 90º in MPMovieplayercontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using `MPMovieplayercontroller` to play video it plays the video which comes from web services. Source video file was taken in potrait mode but it has been rotated 90º in anti-clockwise direction. So when i am playing it in **MPMovieplayercontroller** it is playing like following format attached is the sample image [image]

Is there any way to rotate the video file which comes from web service?

I have tried to apply transform for `MPMovieplayercontroller.view` but movie player controls also rotating. my requirement is i would need to rotate the video part only. Is there any way to achieve this. Please help me out to fix this it would be great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) can help. Try `GPUImageTransformFilter` with `affineTransform` set to `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)`.

Comment: there is no problem in your code this is the video captured in such a way that it shows output like this it's at recording issue so if you put any code for this then it will affect other videos also so don't do anything because nothing is wrong at your end.

Comment: @eptdeveloper i strongly agree your point, i asked my back end team to fix this issue while recording itself they are analyzing to fix this. in between i am trying to find any alternate solution in iOS.

Comment: @thavasidurai : don't find any alternative for this man. because if you find anything that rotates your this video and make it work well will surely rotate other videos also which were recorded correctly so that videos will not work properly just left this video as it is and make your client or whom so ever it may concern that the this video is not recorded with correct dimension so the issue is rising else others are working fine i am sure they understand you well.

Comment: @eptdeveloper thanks for your comments. i need to rotate all the videos those are recorded in the back end. Because all the videos are stored in the rotated format only. So I think it will not be a problem for my requirement

Comment: You will probably have to use the AVPlayer for this as MPMoviePlayerController might not allow changing or manipulating the video in any sort. I will try to see if I can manage a simpler class that will play with the video rotating. But that would mean that you would have to implement your own controls and the default controls wont probably show up.

Comment: Did you had a look to this post: http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html ?

Comment: No, i haven't I will look on it, let you know once it works

Comment: You would need to use the AVFoundation classes to rotate the video using the AVMutableComposition class. Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175060/how-to-control-orientation-of-video-assembled-with-avmutablecomposition. Basically, load the asset into that then apply the CGAffineTransform to M_PI_2. That being said, I've seen this on my own backend before because it wasn't taking the given rotation into account in the switches for ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this: (I have made a subclass for MPMoviePlayerViewController)

```
- (void)configureSubViews
{
    if (self.moviePlayer.view.subviews.count > 0)
    {
        UIView *view = self.moviePlayer.view.subviews[0];
        if (view.subviews.count > 0)
        {
            UIView *sView = view.subviews[0];
            self.viewPlayerVideoContent = [sView viewWithTag:1002];
            self.viewPlayerControls     = [sView viewWithTag:1003];
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really like to work in that way with the subViews, but it works.. (at least for iOS5 and iOS6)

then, you could try to rotate the viewPlayersVideoContent :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to rotate `MPMoviePlayer` view as per the following code. 
This will work best. I have tested it.

```
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Video" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:fileUrl];
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
    moviePlayerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

Comment: Thank you i will test this and let you know

Comment: This will rotate both video view and controls right? for my requirement controls should not rotate

Comment: it is displaying video in landscape mode. but not showing default controls of mpmovieplayer

Comment: It should show . There must be some problem with Struts and Springs

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this by following code,

```
yourMoviePlayerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

and if you want to keep you controls at some place fixed, by default its not possible. So you need to hide the default controls by following code,

```
yourMoviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
```

and then add a subView for the controls programatically.

Comment: Is there any option to use default controls?

Comment: Nope, i don't think so.